# How do I define a data type consisting of other data types?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I want to define the data type Currency, which consists of three other data types. I have the problem that Haskell doesn't recognize the data types as a part of currency, which breaks everything.

My idea was to define the different currencies as their own data types and then add them to the Currency type, which I tried with:

```hs
data Euro = MkEuro Integer Integer
data Dollar = MkDollar Integer Integer
data Yen = MkYen Integer
data Currency = Euro | Dollar | Yen
```

If I want to use the type Currency in any function I get a variation of the following error message:

```hs
Couldn't match expected type `Currency' with actual type `Dollar'
```

Sadly I have to use the type Currency and can't create different functions for all three currencies.

Comment: Perhaps you want to make `data Currency = Euro Int Int | Dollar Int Int | Yen Int Int`. I would use `Float` instead of `Int` though. May be you want to contain the current sell and bid values.. Just guessing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently your `Currency` is constructed as three values, that take *no* parameters. So `Euro` is a value, `Dollar` is a value, and `Yen` is a value, but not `MkYen 15`.

You can add parameters to your data constructors like:

```
data Currency = Euro Euro | Dollar Dollar | Yen Yen
```

Then you thus can construct a `Currency` with:

```
Euro (MkEuro 14 25) :: Currency
```

The `:: Currency` is *not* necessary. The `MkEuro` will thus construct an object of the `Euro` type, and then we use the `Euro` *data* constructor with type `Euro -> Currency` to construct a `Currency`.

> Sadly I have to use the type `Currency` and can't create different functions for all three currencies.

You might want to make a `Currency` *typeclass* however, that provides an interface that says what functions a currency should implement, and then make `Euro`, `Dollar`, and `Yen` instances of that typeclass.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with what you attempted is that the `Euro`, `Dollar` and `Yen` defined on the first 3 lines (on the left-hand-side of the `=` signs) are *types*, whereas those in the last line, on the right-hand-side, are *data constructors*. These are different things, which is why you're allowed to give them the same names - but also means that the *value* `Dollar` has the *type* `Currency`, not the type `Dollar`.

You had the right idea to create a union type combining the other three - but you are confusing the data constructors (which are just "tags") with the types of the values they hold. You can fix it like this:

```
data Currency = Euro Euro | Dollar Dollar | Yen Yen
```

That might look confusing to have the same name twice (three times, too) - but the two occurrences of the name have different meanings. In `Euro Euro`, for example, the first `Euro` is a data constructor (a function which "tags" the value), while the second is the *type* on which the constructor function operates.